# I want to compare if a value is "unavailable" javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout and I want to compare if a value is unavailable or not. Is there a way in JavaScript/knockout I can do this?

```
<!-- ko if: User().details()[0] != undefined -->
       <p>Your defined</p>
<!--/ko-->
```

I have tried `undefined` but that doesn't work. Anybody know what I can compare it with so it checks if the value is unavailable or not?

Comment: This may make sense to be defined as a computed value.

Comment: If the issue is an `object is not a function` error, as you stated below, then you will need to update the question with your knockout model code. It's likely that either `User` or `details` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the `typeof` the value with `'undefined'`. For example:

```
<!-- ko if: typeof User().details()[0] !== 'undefined' -->
       <p>Your defined</p>
<!--/ko-->
```

Please see the [MDN documentation for this type of check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Typeof_operator_and_undefined).

And a snippet that illustrates this:

```js
var x = {
  y: 50
};

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'x.y is undefined: ' + (typeof x.y === 'undefined') + '; x.z is undefined: ' + (typeof x.z === 'undefined');
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show me how i would apply this to my code above?

Comment: @DomAdams In that case, please update your question with some additional code, including your knockout model. Either `User` or `details` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

well instead of checking weather something is undefined and If you are in a dilemma always use `with` (container-less in your scenario) which servers the exact purpose .

**View :**

```
<!-- ko with:$data.User1 --> 
       <p data-bind="text:$data">  defined</p>
<!--/ko-->

<!-- ko if:$data.User -->
       <p>Your defined</p>
<!--/ko-->
```

**View Model:**

```
 var viewModel = {
 User: ko.observable('charlie')
 };
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

In view you can see i intentionally used `with:user1` still your code wont break it simply stop looking further down . If you try the samething for `if` you get undefined error .

Well if you really want to go ahead with `if` then try to use a computed and return true/false based on the conditions you impose . make view cleaner

Working **[sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/22137/)**